# Compatibility between multiple generic protocols

Tags: python, generics, python-typing

My problem is similar to the one posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67404067/how-to-use-typevar-for-input-and-output-of-multiple-generic-protocols-in-python). In that question, the protocols C and D which we want to be compatible are generic over another type A. But we want C to depend on D and D to also depend on C, something like this (not actually valid code):

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Protocol, Generic
from dataclasses import dataclass

C = TypeVar("C", bound=CClass)
D = TypeVar("D", bound=DClass)

class CProto(Protocol[D]):
    def f(self, d: D) -> None: pass

class DProto(Protocol[C]):
    def g(self) -> C: pass


@dataclass
class CompatibleThings(Generic[C,D]):
    c: C
    d: D
```

The renaming below might explain my use case a bit better. I want "variable" and "expression" protocols, whose instances can be added together to make new expressions.

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Protocol, Generic
from dataclasses import dataclass

Var = TypeVar("Var")
Expr = TypeVar("Expr")

class VarProto(Protocol[Expr]):
    def __add__(self, expr: Expr) -> Expr

class ExprProto(Protocol[Var]):
    def __add__(self, x: Var) -> Expr


@dataclass
class CompatibleThings(Generic[Var,Expr]):
    x: Var
    expr: Expr
```

Is there a way to achieve something like this?

Comment: For your practical problem, do you actually need to treat the variables and expressions as separate? Usually, references to variables are *a kind of* expressions themselves.

Comment: Can you clarify which problem exactly you are trying to solve? Is it the co/contra/invariance of the type vars, or is it defining the specific set of interdependent types?